# What are the user-friendly pieces in Ubuntu, which Debian doesn't have?

Tags: debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is Ubuntu different from Debian?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336/how-is-ubuntu-different-from-debian)

I've read this line of "Ubuntu is more user-friendly than Debian" many times, and I wonder where all the differences lie.

I do acknowledge that Ubuntu is somewhat more friendly for people with weaker computer skills, especially as far as the installation and drivers go. But what else is there? I am a Linux newbie, but I have a bit of experience with managing computers and as soon as I grasped certain glaring differences between the way certain things are on Linux and on Windows (the file system, packages, almighty terminal, root...), I ceased to be able to differentiate much between the two distros (visuals and release cycles aside).

Could you, please, give me some examples of those preconfigurations and services that the fresh Debian installation presumably lacks?
For example, when I was using Debian and wrote some files to a mounted NTFS partition, I shutdown the OS without unmounting first, and the partition was left in a messy state. Would the same thing happen in Ubuntu, or is there some kind of safety fuse that would prevent this from happening?

Comment: I understand that it is a broad question in principle, but the other thread is pretty much about the obvious differences and philosophies behind the distros, rather than technical details. It can't give me an answer to my question about handling mounted partitions. Another thing that comes to my mind is: are there differences in the way the firewall defaults are set up? I could ask each of those questions in a separate thread, but that probably wouldn't do any good. Isn't there a comprehensive list of the technical differences?

Comment: A distribution is nothing but "a set of software".Distributions are mainly based on the same source files, only the versions, update periods and by default installed software are different. Thus it is just a matter of sympatisation. What really decides about the success of a distri is (on my opinion) the way, updates and problems are handeled. The distributor tries to hide all difficult stuff from the user. Ubuntu seems to do a very good job and is therefor very common. However, Ubuntu still depends on debian.I e.g. use both, I prefere debian on headless servers and ubuntu on desktop pc.