# What packages are in Ubuntu but not in Debian?

Tags: debian

Ubuntu uses packages from Debian (it is based on Debian).

I wonder what extra packages or package classes are added to Ubuntu?

I expect to see some proprietary software, some extra office software, some build-in adware...

Let's compare with latest stable releases. But it doesn't hurt if you add some important historical notes too...

I am talking only about official upstream package repositories. No need to talk about PPA.

I am not interested in branding or styling or release cycle or support or whatever discussed at [How is Ubuntu different from Debian?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336/how-is-ubuntu-different-from-debian) difference. Only about the difference in packages and that link doesn't tell anything related they I haven't mentioned in my question.

Comment: I added reasoning why my question isn't the same as moderators like to be,

Comment: Don't think there is an easy way to compare, also, ...what's the point? Generally, Ubuntu packages are a shapshot of Debian unstable or testing.

Comment: @mikewhatever Is it purely a copy of `testing` or there are extra packages on top of Debian?

Comment: `apt list` plus some additional CLI magic (`sort`, `uniq`, `awk`, etc.)  should do the trick. You should try to do it yourself as an exercise.

Comment: @fkraiem if the OP knew how to do that, they would not have asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use, https://www.distrowatch.com to compare versions of the packages that are available for installation from official repositories.

For example this [link](https://www.distrowatch.com/dwres.php?firstlist=debian&secondlist=ubuntu&firstversions=2&secondversions=2&resource=compare-packages&view=all.).

Answer (score -1):

I tried:

```
debian# apt list | sed 's=/.*==' | sort >debian.list
ubuntu# apt list | sed 's=/.*==' | sort >ubuntu.list
```

and then:

```
diff -u debian.list ubuntu.list | cdiff
```

under WSL and it was mess... Probably because different flavor of repositories are enabled in both distros...